# How to check header regex in response with Spring MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I have the an API that should return a response containing the header `HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION` with a value that should match the regex `"prefix(.*?)suffix"`.

My test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final MyRequest request = MyRequest.builder()
            .field("bla")
            .build();

    var res = mockMvc.perform(post("my-uri")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request)))
            .andExpectAll(status().isOk(),
                    header().string(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, matches("prefix(.*?)suffix")),
                    header().string(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

When running it I'm getting this error: `You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.`

Any idea how can I check the header CONTENT_DISPOSITION?

Answer (score 0):

Well ChatGPT won...
this works:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final MyRequest request = MyRequest.builder()
            .field("bla")
            .build();

    var res = mockMvc.perform(post("my-uri")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request)))
            .andExpectAll(status().isOk(),
                    header().exists(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION),
                    header().string(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse();
    
    System.out.println(res);
    assertTrue(res.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION).matches("prefix(.*?)suffix"));
    }
```

Comment: [*Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)